# Why do I always get "It does not meet our quality standards"

Tags: discussion, comments

I just do the normal way of making a question but always says 'It does not meet our quality standards.' is there something wrong about my writings?

Answer (score 11):

The site expects certain things from posts in order to pass the quality filter.

Just from scanning them; you should probably fix up some of the punctuation and capitalization of your posts and probably cut down on some of your [textspeak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_language).

Comment: Now I got it. thx